# Change transparency for ToolStrip submenu

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip, contextmenustrip

I am tampering with ToolStrip modifications as of now and is trying to make the submenu also transparent like the MenuStrip. I can't manage to make the submenu's property to be like the menu itself.

How do I do that?

Here's my code for the modifications:

```
    public class ArrowRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {
        public ArrowRenderer() : base(new LeftMenuColorTable())
        {

        }
        protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            var tsMenuItem = e.Item as ToolStripMenuItem;
            if (tsMenuItem != null)
                e.TextColor = Color.White;
            base.OnRenderItemText(e);
        }

        protected override void OnRenderArrow(ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            var tsMenuItem = e.Item as ToolStripMenuItem;
            if (tsMenuItem != null)
                e.ArrowColor = Color.White;
            base.OnRenderArrow(e);
        }
        protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            var tsMenuItem = e.Item as ToolStripMenuItem;
            if (tsMenuItem != null)
                e.Item.BackColor = Color.Black;
            base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e);
        }
    }
    public class LeftMenuColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
    { 
        public override Color MenuItemSelected
        {
            // when the menu is selected
            get { return ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#494f52");  }
        }

        public override Color ToolStripBorder
        {
            get { return ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF"); }
        }
        public override Color ToolStripDropDownBackground
        {
            get { return Color.White; }
        }
    }

    internal void SetTrayMenu()
    {
        if (m_menu != null)
            if (notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip != null)
                notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Refresh();

        m_menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
        m_menu.Renderer = new ArrowRenderer();
        m_menu.AllowTransparency = true;
        m_menu.Opacity = 0.8;

        m_menu.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the [ToolStripDropDownMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownmenu?view=netcore-3.1) that hosts/lists the sub items or [DropDownItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownitem.dropdownitems?view=netcore-3.1) is not the same object that the [ContextMenuStrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip?view=netcore-3.1) inherits. Hence you need to apply the same settings for each sub menu or [DropDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown?view=netcore-3.1).

The `SetTrayMenu()` should do:

```cs
internal void SetTrayMenu()
{
    if (m_menu != null && notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip != null)
        //Why?
        notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Refresh();
    else
    {
        m_menu = new ContextMenuStrip
        {
            Renderer = new ArrowRenderer(),
            AllowTransparency = true,
            Opacity = 0.8,
        };

        foreach (var dd in m_menu.Items.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>()
            .Where(x => x.HasDropDown))
        {
            var ddm = dd.DropDown as ToolStripDropDownMenu;

            if (ddm != null)
            {
                ddm.AllowTransparency = true;
                ddm.Opacity = 0.8;
            }
        }

        m_menu.BackColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

**Before**

[image: SOQ61911652A]

**After**

[image: SOQ61911652]

<sup>**Note:** Opacity = 0.5 here.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how do I change the border color of the sub-menus?

Comment: @TerribleDog Most welcome buddy. To you need to override the `MenuBorder` as well in the `LeftMenuColorTable` class. e.g. `public override Color MenuBorder => ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");`

Comment: @TerribleDog No it will change. just set another color like `Color.Red` to see. As for the `ToolStripSeparator`, yes it ignores the back color. You need to derive a new class from it and override the `OnPaint` method instead. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31093769/10216583) out. Also you can derive a new class from `ToolStripMenuItem` to draw something better. I've published something like [this](https://github.com/q8soft/WinFrmSkins.NYX/blob/master/src/NYX/NYXToolStripSeparator.vb) in this context. Its VB.NET though. I believe you can manage that :)

Comment: Yes, thank you for it, I had overlapping codes that prevented the change but there is one more question, https://imgur.com/a/ZhPU2gj How do I remove the border on the left side?

Comment: @TerribleDog This requires overriding the `OnRenderToolStripBorder` method in the `ArrowRenderer` class to check which type of `e.ToolStrip` and draw the `e.AffectedBounds` accordingly. e.g. `if (e.ToolStrip is ContextMenuStrip) { //draw the border }; else if (e.ToolStrip is ToolStripDropDownMenu) { }; else base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);` and forget overriding the `MenuBorder` property as I mentioned above. You might need to reduce both the width and height of `e.AffectedBounds` rectangle by 1.

Comment: I did this using ImageMarginGradientBegin. Thanks so much

Comment: @TerribleDog Welcome bud. Anytime.